# Why arent my new resources added in the res/ sub-folders showing up in the R class?

Tags: android, resources, paint

I don't understand why Eclipse doesn't know how to resolve the color resources I've defined. Am I doing something wrong?

R.color.notepad_lines cannot be resolved MyNewTextView.java

I've had problems before too with eclipse being able to find images in my /res/drawable directory

/res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="notepad_paper">#AAFFFF99</color>
 <color name="notepad_lines">#FF0000FF</color>
 <color name="notepad_margin">#90FF0000</color>
 <color name="notepad_text">#AA0000FF</color>
</resources>
```

MyNewTextView.java

```
...
 private Paint marginPaint;
 private Paint linePaint;
 private int paperColor;
 private float margin; 


 private void init(){
  //Get Reference to Resource Table
  Resources myRes = getResources();

  //Create paint brushes
  marginPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  marginPaint.setColor(myRes.getColor(R.color.notepad_margin));

  linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  linePaint.setColor(myRes.getColor(R.color.notepad_lines));

  paperColor = myRes.getColor(R.color.notepad_paper);
  margin = myRes.getDimension(R.dimen.notepad_margin);
 }

...
```

Eclipse keeps saying it can't find any of the R.* resources =/

R.java

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }

public static final class color {
    public static final int notepad_lines=0x7f040001;
    public static final int notepad_margin=0x7f040002;
    public static final int notepad_paper=0x7f040000;
    public static final int notepad_text=0x7f040003;
}
public static final class dimen {
    public static final int notepad_margin=0x7f050000;
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_menu_add=0x7f020000;
    public static final int ic_menu_cut=0x7f020001;
    public static final int ic_menu_king=0x7f020002;
    public static final int icon=0x7f020003;
}
...
```

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  It won't find the newly added R resources until after you build, since the R file is autogenerated at that point.

Comment: I have build automatically checked. and Ive done the clean build thing a few times already =/

Comment: What do you see in the R file?  Are any of your resources in there?

Comment: @codeninja: Your build is probably failing. Look at your console for `aapt` errors (e.g., invalid XML).

Comment: Thanks I've checked for that but there arent any XML error messages in my console. There were Socket error messages when I tried to restart ADB

Comment: @codeninja So you are sure that R is being generated?  It doesn't have to be xml error messages, anything that prevents the compilation from completing.

Comment: I made some edits above to show that those items are actually in R.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem too, unless I let Eclipse create the file, rather that drop the XML file in under *res/* somewhere.  But I just found a way around this:
In the Project Explorer view, find the *res/values* directory and select **refresh** from the right click menu:
[image]

*colors.xml* now appears in the explorer, and the *R.java* now contains the `R.color` class. Rebuild it you don't auto-rebuild.

Comment: Did you just make that right now, or are you doing the same example that I am? ^_^ Unfortunately refresh did not solve the issue for me

Comment: I just tried to solve this because I was having the same problem when I tried to add pre-existing files. I'm not on the same project. Eclipse seems to ignore new files by default. I created a file in XEmacs with your xml and saved it as res/colors.xml. I added`int  `line_color=R.color.notepad_lines;` in the main `Activity` class which is just a clone of my HelloWorld project. I could not build, because gen/.../R.java did not define the `color` class.   After refresh,  the R.java got updated and the project built find.

Comment: Yeah it seems to only "fix" when I hit Run As > Android App, and no other time =/

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that: In my case, my package is package org.frayser.practice;  R.java defines class color as org.frayser.practice.R.colors.  <- Those are my pre-defined colors from colors.xml.  `android.R.color` is another `R.color` class that has a different set of pre-defined colors. [See the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html), then compare to your *R.java.*

Comment: For this to work, there need to be a *gen/your/package/path/R.java* file. The *R.java* should have `package your.package` declared.  Inside the file should be `class R` with a inner `class color` with some `int` values defined.  My original problem was that the R.java never got updated with `class color`, plus *colors.xml* didn't even show up in the *Project Explorer*. Seems you have a *R.java.*  with `color`s in it. Check the package names.

Comment: OMG! I had "import android.R" which didnt seem like the right path, but taking that out seemed to fix it =/

Comment: `android.R.colors` was shadowing your`R.colors`  Glad you got it fixed.  It's weird how Android uses the same class name rather than  a different one, or subclassing.

Comment: shadowing? what does that mean

Comment: Two packages, classes, namespaces etc export the same name.  When you look for the name you get the wrong one because you didn't know there were two, or you mistakenly wrote the wrong code.  `Point(x,y){ this.x = x; this.y=y; }` Used this.x because there were two x's one shadowed the other. See 6.3.1. [Shadowing Declarations]:(http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#34133)

Comment: There is a [standard R.color class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html). There is an entire [android.R](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html). So if you `import android.R`, you *shadow* yow own `R.color`, and `R.*`, _from mypackage.R.java_. Compare the [standard R.color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.htm) to your own R.color, and see the difference in color names.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you are not importing the provided android Resource class 'import android.R' but your own generated Resource class e.g. import .R

Answer (score 1):

This may be a stupid suggestion but... Is *MyNewTextView.java* in the same package name as the *R.java* file? If not, then you need to add a reference to the package via an import statement.

Comment: No, good suggestion. The package name isn't shown on any of the sample sources.

Comment: Yeah it was a good suggestion this exactly was the problem. The package path for R was different than where R.java was generating.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the R.java file in the gen folder...